# Update Multiple Fields of Dataframe from Function return values using Apply, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have dataframe with "Indicator_Name" field which contains some text and I am aplying some function which returs 2 values and needs to update same in the Dataframe

Function "String_Year_Pick_V2" returns two values like "XYZ", 'ABC', needs to add these values against each "Indicator_Name"

I have tried below script:

```
DataT[['Indicator 2', 'Year']] = DataT['Indicator_Name'].apply(String_Year_Pick_V2, axis=1)

Error:
TypeError: String_Year_Pick_V2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

DataT[['Indicator 2', 'Year']] = DataT['Indicator_Name'].apply(String_Year_Pick_V2)
Error: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (252,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,252
```

Script: DataT['Indicator_Name'].apply(String_Year_Pick_V2) - gives  results

```
DataT[['Indicator 2', 'Year']] = DataT.apply(lambda Row: String_Year_Pick_V2(Row['Indicator_Name']), axis=1)
Error: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (252,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,252)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Series` in output of function:

```
def String_Year_Pick_V2(x):
    #your code
    year = x + 2000
    ind = x + 10
    return pd.Series([ind, year])

DataT = pd.DataFrame({'Indicator_Name':[1,2,3]})

DataT[['Indicator 2', 'Year']] = DataT['Indicator_Name'].apply(String_Year_Pick_V2)
print (DataT)
   Indicator_Name  Indicator 2  Year
0               1           11  2001
1               2           12  2002
2               3           13  2003
```